# Linked List Cycle Potential Exception

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Below is the code to detect if a linked-list contains a loop:

```
  public static boolean containsCycle(LinkedListNode firstNode) {

// start both runners at the beginning
LinkedListNode slowRunner = firstNode;
LinkedListNode fastRunner = firstNode;

// until we hit the end of the list
while (fastRunner != null && fastRunner.next != null) {
    slowRunner = slowRunner.next;
    fastRunner = fastRunner.next.next;

    // case: fastRunner is about to "lap" slowRunner
    if (fastRunner == slowRunner) {
        return true;
    }
}

// case: fastRunner hit the end of the list
return false;
```

Shouldn't the condition of the while loop be fastRunner != null && fastRunner.next.NEXT!= null? With the current code, fastRunner can be the very last node in the linked list, and so once the while loop is entered, the next node of the last node will result in an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the current code, fastRunner can be the very last node in the linked list

`fastRunner` cannot be the very last node in the linked list, because your `while` loop

```
while (fastRunner != null && fastRunner.next != null) {
```

checks that `fastRunner` is not the last element (since `fastRunner.next == null` would mean that `fastRunner` is the last element). This assignment in your loop

```
fastRunner = fastRunner.next.next;
```

can certainly set `fastRunner` to `null`, but you aren't doing anything with it that would cause a null pointer exception, and the next iteration of the `while` loop will exit (since now `fastRunner == null`)

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is certainly correct, provided thread safety is not an issue. 
 In other words, if the list is changed by code in another thread while this method is running, then it can certainly yield either an incorrect result or a `NullPointerException`.

However, if your code is single-threaded, then the  `NullPointerException` can't ever happen.  For this code to throw a `NullPointerException`, there would have to be a `.` operator, with a null value to its left.  Although there are other types of code that can throw a `NullPointerException`, such as auto-unboxing null values, and using null arguments in for-each loops; you don't have any of these.

So to see this code can throw a `NullPointerException`, you should consider every `.` operator in your code in turn.  There are four dots to consider.

1. The dot in `while (fastRunner != null && fastRunner.next != null) {` - this can't ever cause a `NullPointerException`, because this code is only checked if `fastRunner` is not null, thanks to short-circuit evaluation.
2. The dot in `slowRunner = slowRunner.next;` - this can't ever cause a `NullPointerException`, because every value that `slowRunner` takes has already been taken, either by `fastRunner` or `fastRunner.next`. Therefore,  if `slowRunner` were null, you would have already got the `NullPointerException`.  You can't get it from this dot.
3. The first dot in `fastRunner = fastRunner.next.next;` - this can't ever cause a `NullPointerException`, because you've already checked that `fastRunner` is not null.
4. The second dot in `fastRunner = fastRunner.next.next;` - this can't ever cause a `NullPointerException`, because you've already checked that `fastRunner.next` is not null.

So there is no point in your code that can possibly cause a `NullPointerException`, unless the list is changed by a second thread while the code is executing.